# git reset all branches to origin?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-reset

I want to reset multiple branches to their origin version. So,

```
git fetch --all
for b in master work; do
  git switch $b; git reset --hard origin/$b
done
```

But simpler? I've thought about deleting all branches so they get recreated, but one has to be checked out and will error out.

**Edit**: the scenario is that `origin` often rewrites multiple branches with impunity. The answer below also gave me the idea of saving various states to backup refs -- which is a nice bonus.

Comment: Simpler in what sense?

Comment: You can just delete all other branches if their names match that from the remote. A new one will be created from `origin/example` when you try to `git checkout example`.

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do? If it's only about resetting the local branches to their corresponding 'origin' state, I suppose it's easier just to drop the ones that do have upstream counterparts.

Comment: Drop and recreate, so that there exists a local copy "just in case". I've thought about that, but it's still 2 * N commands, plus one of the branches will be checked out and would need even more commands to handle

Comment: The `why` here doesn't make sense, you already have the remote refs whether they match the local branch commit or not. What is the root-problem you're considering here?

Comment: Being subscribed to a repo whose author often rewrites history (so pull --all doesn't work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>You don't need to switch to the branches. You can simply re-create a branch and have it point to any arbitrary ref:</s>

```
git branch -f branchname "$target"
```

(As an added bonus, unstaged changes in your working tree won't be affected, as compared to `git reset --hard` which will wipe any local changes.)

When being used in scripts `git branch` should be avoided and it is better to use [`for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref):

```
git for-each-ref 'refs/remotes/origin' --format='%(refname:strip=3)' \
| while read ref; do
    git branch -f "$ref" "origin/$ref";
done
```

---

If you are only interested in creating a "backup" of the current state of the remote tracking branches, `git push` or `git fetch` can help by using the current clone as remote.

Either command will replicate all branches of the `origin` remote into a new (local) branch hierarchy with prefix `backup/`, i.e. `origin/dev` becomes `backup/dev`:

```
git fetch . 'refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/backup/*'
# or:
git push . 'refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/backup/*'
```

Or to fetch directly from the remote into a separate set of local refs:

```
git fetch origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/backup/*'
```

Comment: That's better; though it won't work for the currently checked out branch, and it still needs N commands (or a `for` loop). I suppose an alias would do.

Comment: ^ was for your 1st version. Based on your 2nd version, I've also found `git push . 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/backup-*'`

Comment: @usretc `git push . 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/backup-*` will only copy your existing local branches, and not any remote-tracking branches. It will not reset your local branches to their matching remote parts either.

Comment: yes, I'm just trying out everything. The scenario is that `origin` rewrites history with impunity. So, I often want to reset all local branches to "their" version. Your post also gave me the idea of saving current state, which is a nice bonus.

Comment: OK, I've tested all the `push *:*` combinations, and it's nice that they create real branches, saving the real state of the affected files; these work even if `origin` rewrites history. Neither of these resets local `x` to origin/`x`. For that, your striked out answer works -- except not even `branch -f` can update the checked out branch

Comment: ... for the checked out branch, `git reset --hard $(git branch --show-current) $(git name-rev @{u})` does it

Comment: @usretc I departed from the original solution of re-creating all local branches, because it is a destructive operation that is hard to reverse. Your comments stated that you wanted to create "backups" of the `origin` remote due to frequent history rewriting. Replicating the remote structure in a separate hierarchy gives you the backup, without overwriting/destroying any of your local refs. But nevermind, whatever works best for your scenario. You can achieve the same outcome of the original solution with `fetch origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` – that will _overwrite_ all your local refs.

Comment: `fetch origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` would be nice, but: `fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository`.

Comment: Ah, finally: `fetch -u -f origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'`